# How to create local git repository from git archive?

Tags: git, git-archive

Is it possible to recreate a git repository locally from the extracted content of a Github repository archive ?

To add a little bit of context, my Android app downloads a git repository archive using DownloadManager and a Github repository archive link, then extracts it on the local storage of the device. I am looking to turn the content of this extracted archive into a local repository of the remote one and track its contents.

Comment: As far as I understand, archive only contains single snapshot of repository, but not entire history.

Answer (score 1):

It is not, alas. The result of `git archive` contains neither commits nor other metadata.

The only way to track a remote repository is to clone it.